# Repository content (files/directories) not showing at new location on svn dump and load

Tags: svn, dump, svnadmin

I want to move my repo to new server. My repo contains multiple files. To move I have created a repository dump file with command

```
$svnadmin dump file:///repo/path > file.dump
```

copied dump file to new server and loaded the dump file in new repository with command

```
$svnadmin load file:///new/repo/path < file.dump
```

It successfully loaded the file with log

```
<<< Started new transaction, based on original revision 1
------- Committed new rev 1 (loaded from original rev 1) >>>
```

I am not able to see files and folders which I have loaded from dump file at new repository location. Please help if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, the commands you've specified should not work. You have to specify full local path to repository and not use `file://` access. `svnadmin` is an admin tool that requires local and full access the repository and it does not accept URLs.

The commands should be

- `svnadmin dump /path/to/repository > file.dump`
- `svnadmin load /path/to/new/repository < file.dump`

After loading the dump, use Subversion client and run `svn log` to check the revision history in the new repository.

With `svn log`, you must enter URL to the repository. In case you plan to check the log locally, specify `file://path/to/new/repository`.